# How to compute the present value of a liability

Tags: liability

There is a liability which will owe
*x* dollars per year in *n* years with interest rate *r* (annual compounding).
Is the present value of this liability given by:

```
sum(x/(1+r)^i)
```

or

```
sum(x(1+r)^i)
```

In other words, are there differences in calculating present value of a bond and of a liability or loan?

Thanks!

Comment: MathJax tags don't work in this forum (the support is forum-by-forum).

Answer (score 2):

To the "in other words" portion. No. My debt to the bank (a mortgage) looks like a bond to the bank in terms of valuation. Your question can be solved by first calculating the present value of a payment stream, and then just reduce to account for delay till that stream starts, i.e. since there's a delay till the PV is reached, the time until the payment stream starts. A financial calculator makes these calculations pretty simple.